# The JavaScript code for the note-taking app is not storing notes in local storage

Tags: javascript, html

```
const noteContainer = document.querySelector(".note-container");
const createBtn = document.querySelector(".btn");
let notes = document.querySelectorAll(".input-box");

function showNotes() {
  noteContainer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("notes")
}
showNotes();


function updateStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem("data", noteContainer.innerHTML);

}

createBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let inputBox = document.createElement("p")
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  inputBox.className = "input-box";
  inputBox.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
  img.src = "images/delete.png";
  noteContainer.appendChild(inputBox).appendChild(img);

})
noteContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    updateStorage();
  } else if (e.target.tagName === "P") {
    notes = document.querySelectorAll(".input-box");
    notes.forEach(nt => {
      nt.onkeyup = function() {
        updateStorage();
      }

    })
  }
})
```

I tried to store notes in local storage using the `localStorage.setItem()` function. I expected the notes to be stored correctly and to be accessible even after the page was refreshed. However, the notes were not stored correctly. Instead, the `localStorage.setItem()` function was trying to store a DOM node, which is not permitted. The actual result was that the notes were not stored in local storage and were lost when the page was refreshed.

Comment: *"was trying to store a DOM node"*  The `localStorage.setItem()` tries to set whatever you pass as second parameter. In your case this is `noteContainer.innerHTML` which is a `string` (maybe not the string you want, but nevertheless, it's a string) ... and as @mykaf pointed out: You are using two different keys for the localstorage.

Comment: You are using two different key names for getting and setting. `notes` vs `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. `noteContainer.innerHTML` shall be a string type, so there should be no problems. 
Well, localStorage supports only plain text items. 
 Futhermore, you need to be careful when using this technology, because it depends on user privacy settings. So store something is not actually good idea. 
I recommend to stringify item before setting it to the storage. 
Just like:

```
try { // check availabity is a good style
  localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringy("..data")) // export
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name")) // import
  } 
catch { /* handle error */ }
```

Also notice `.append(Element)` is not the same to `.innerHTML` 
the first case is much more clear-working, easy reading and modifying. 
Hope this helps..